# Generators of additive groups of even order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working in some problems:

> I need to know the generators of additive groups of even order (other than one). In general, if $x$ is a generator of a group $\mathbb Z_{2n}$, then $x = \;$?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking?

Comment: 1 generates the additive group Z/nZ. E.g. {1,1+1,1+1+1} = Z/3Z.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are asking. That said,

$\langle x \rangle = \mathbb Z_{2n}$ if and only if $x$ is relatively prime to $2n$, if and only if $\gcd(x, 2n) = 1$.

To find the number of generators of $\mathbb Z_{2n}$, i.e., the number of integers relatively prime to $2n$, use [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient_function) and compute $\varphi(2n)$. If you want to count all generators *other than* $1$, then compute $\varphi(2n) - 1$.

***In answer to your comment below:***

There is no particular "$x$" that generates all additive groups of even order $2n,\;n\geq 1$, save for $1$ itself. Else, any generator $x$ depends on $n$. For example, $3$ generates $Z_4, \,Z_8, \,Z_{10}, \,Z_{14},...$, but does not generate $Z_6, \, Z_{12},....$. The same thing happens if we try $x = 5$ ...or $x = 7$, or ...

Comment: K thanks. But its well known result. But i need  a particular ' x' for all 2n. For example x = 1, gcd(1,2n)=1, gcd(2n-1,2n)=1, gcd(3n-1,2n)=1, gcd(4n-1,2n)=1 ... and so on. In general gcd(kn-1,2n)=1 for some integer k. I need other than this.

Comment: There is no particular "x" that generates all additive groups of even order $2n,\;n\geq 1$, save for $1$. Else, it depends on $n$. For example, $3$ generates $Z_4, Z_8, Z_{10}, Z_{14}, ...$ but does not generate $Z_6, Z_{12}, ...$. The same thing happens if we try $5$...or $7$, or ...

Comment: +1 there is a nice theorem i think in Hungerford about it.